How do I calculate nozzle flow with chemical kinetics?
I found Krieger's 1951 paper titled "Chemical Kinetics and Rocket Nozzle Design" in which he derives the following differential equation for the rate of formation of atomic hydrogen in the conical nozzle of a pure hydrogen thermal rocket (throat conditions assumed to be $85\%$ $H_2$ and $15\% H$ at 3500 $K$).
$-\dfrac{d N_H}{d x}=\dfrac{k_f\left(2-N_H\right)}{v(R T)^2}\left(N_{H^2} P^2-N_{H_2} P / K_p\right)$
$N_H$ - Mole fraction of hydrogen atoms 
$N_{H_2}$ - mole fraction of hydrogen molecules 
$k_f$ - forward rate of reaction 
$R$ - gas const. 
$T$ - temperature 
$P$ - pressure 
$K_p$ - equilibrium constant
To solve this numerically, he suggests multiplying the equation by $\dfrac{dx}{dT}$ in which $x$ is pos. along nozzle and $T$ is temperature.
My question is, how does multiplying by $\dfrac{dx}{dT}$ overcome the fact that $v(x), P(x), T(x)$ are not known ab initio? The only way I can think to solve this is to calculate $v(x), P(x), T(x)$ using isentropic expansion and then calculate chemical kinetics using the equation above - but this will be highly inaccurate and won't give me the results Krieger obtained. Krieger does not seem to clarify this doubt of mine and considering he has long since passed away I am a bit stuck. How can I replicate his results with his method?
